# Broadcast messages

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, chat

How about adding a broadcast feature to chat.meta ,similar to irc chanserv. This could be used to broadcast server wide messages to all rooms by admins.

Comment: Who knows, maybe they can already do that...

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with nickserv; nickserv is for registering nicks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already have that. We rarely need to use it, but we can - for example to warn of planned system downtime. This appears both "live" in chats, and on all the auxiliary screens.

Comment: You truly are like gods... *HAIL TO THE GODS*!!